# Error al abrir la terminal integrada de Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio

Cuando quiero abrir la terminar integrada de Visual Studio Code me sale este error, alguien sabe como solucionarlo? por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser por que tal vez no tenga permisos

Comment: verifica en la configuración json de vscode si no cambiaste la ruta de la terminal.

Comment: solo tengo esto en el json, no se si este mal
{
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "angular.experimental-ivy": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    }
}